# Самая первая загрузка машинного кода в память

Tags: ассемблер, машинный-код

Как самый первый машинный код попадал в память, тем самым делая просто метал - компьютером?

Comment: Что-нибудь наподобие "Архитектура ЭВМ и основы ОС" вам подойдёт?

Comment: он попадал через программатор. куча переключателей, через которые вводились битики данных и адреса.

Comment: Для ознакомления можно почитать "Код" Чарльза Петцольда.

Comment: Уточните, что конкретно вы имеете в виду под фразой «самый первый»? Первый относительно чего?

Comment: В 90-х годах на подростковых кружках учили, как загонять в память программу в машинных кодах без других программ. 2 ряда электрических тумблеров (выключателей) - в первом ряду состояния тумблеров приводят в соответствие с двоичным кодом адреса ячейки памяти, куда нужно загрузить, а второй ряд - двоичный код содержимого. Осталось нажать на аппаратную кнопку загрузить. Об этом описывается в книге "ЭВМ своими руками", кто автор не помню.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[В феврале 2021 года первому компьютеру современного типа исполнилось ровно 75 лет](https://hi-news.ru/technology/pervomu-sovremennomu-kompyuteru-ispolnilos-75-let-kakim-on-byl.html). Речь идет о компьютере ENIAC, про существование которого стало известно 15 февраля 1946 года.

...

> В компьютер ENIAC было невозможно устанавливать программы, как на нынешние ноутбуки и другие устройства. Поэтому для выполнения разных задач его приходилось настраивать заново. Для этого операторам приходилось тянуть провода к разным разъемам, крутить регуляторы и выполнять много других действий. В те времена этой работе даже не было официального названия. Но, по сути, операторы ENIAC были первыми в истории программистами. На программирование уходили недели, а на отладку — целые недели.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Еще в 1888 году инженер Герман Холлерит, основатель IBM, создал первую электромеханическую счетную машину - табулятор, который мог считывать и сортировать данные, закодированные на перфокартах (бумажных карточках с отверстиями). Его даже использовали при переписи населения в 1890 году в США. Табуляторы и позднее компьютеры первого поколения, в 1920-х—1950-х годах, использовали перфокарты в качестве основного носителя при хранении и обработке данных. Затем, в течение 1970-х — начале 1980-х годов, они использовались только для хранения данных и постепенно были замещены магнитными лентами. В информатике перфокарты впервые были применены в «аналитической машине» Бэббиджа и в «интеллектуальных машинах» коллежского советника С. Н. Корсакова.

Источник: [Перфокарта](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B0)