# Каким образом совершался ввод команд с помощь ассемблера?

Tags: ассемблер, история

Этот вопрос ставит меня в ступор. Я имею ввиду следующее:

1. как машина форматировала код ассемблера в машинный код?
2. Как осуществлялся ввод кода ассемблера?
   Буду очень благодарен, если ответите мне на эти вопросы

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Самая первая загрузка машинного кода в память](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1248448/%d0%a1%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bc%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c)

Comment: @insolor ну тут не про машинный код, а про ассемблер, это другое)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Никак. Для каждой машины был собственный интерфейс для изменения регистров или участков памяти, предполагаю что существовали отдельные платы для изменения байтов памяти в конкретных участках на конкретные значения, и данные платы были встроены в общую архитектуру первых процессоров. Машинный код - набор МАШИННЫХ а не текстовых команд. Если же вы говорите про ЯЗЫК ассемблера - предположу что изначально все команды переводились в байткод для каждой машины отдельно вручную, после чего на этой же машине и писали простой компилятор языка ассемблера на этом же ассемблере (это довольно тривиальная задача)

Comment: Вообще .ассемблер - это транслятор с ЯЗЫКА ассемблера в машинные команды. А язык ассемблера - это набор текстовых команд, в большинстве своем имеющих прямое соответствие с машинными, и вводились эти команды в первых текстовых редакторах. А интерфейсы для изменения регистров и байтов памяти появились заметно раньше, и к ассемблеру отношения не имеют.

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов Вообще ассемблер понятие растяжимое) Однако в моём случае да, я ошибся, надо было писать не ассемблер, а машинный код. Сейчас исправлю

Comment: Да не так, чтобы сильно растяжимое. Но все же, обратите внимание, вопрос был об ассемблере.  И еще одно.... Байткод - изобретение относительно недавнее, и к ассемблеру отношения не имеет.